# Cycling Through Arrays of Associative Arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this (I'm only showing three records, there are many, many more)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Johnson, John
        [telephonenumber] => 555.555.555
        [department] => Department A
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Johnson, Bill
        [telephonenumber] => 555.555.4444
        [department] => Department B
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Johnson, Carry
        [telephonenumber] => 555.555.3333
        [department] => Department C
    )
)
```

There will be multiple members of Department A, B, etc. and I need to loop through this data and spit out only members of Department A. I have tried:

```
if ($phoneList['department'] == 'Falmouth') {
    echo $phoneList['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $phoneList['telephonenumber'] . '<br>';
    echo $phoneList['department'] . '<br><br>';
}
```

But I am getting errors because I think `$phoneList['department']` doesn't exist (shouldn't be `$phoneList[0]['department']`)?

Either way, that won't help... how can I search through all 90 of these arrays and only print out those with Department A status?

$phoneList is the variable being passed to my view **(using codeigniter, ldap and php)**

Comment: Iterate using `foreach` and check `department`, or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was doing... but I was using = instead of ==, and it was throwing everything off! Sometimes I just need to write things out to figure it out... thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `foreach`:

```
foreach($phoneList as $item)
{
  if($item['department'] == 'Falmouth')
  {
    echo $phoneList['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $phoneList['telephonenumber'] . '<br>';
    echo $phoneList['department'] . '<br><br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Josh has it right, you should be using something like:

```
foreach( $phoneList as $item) {
    if( $item['department'] == 'Falmouth') {
        echo $item['name'] . '<br>';
        echo $item['telephonenumber'] . '<br>';
        echo $item['department'] . '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

You could even replace the inner part of the foreach loop with a call to [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

```
foreach( $phoneList as $item) {
    if( $item['department'] == 'Falmouth') {
        echo implode( '<br>', $item) . '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try
foreach($phoneList as $key => $data)
{

    if($data['department'] == 'DepartmentA')
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$testNeedle = 'DepartmentS';
foreach( array_filter( $phonelist,
                       function($arrayEntry) use ($testNeedle) {
                           return $arrayEntry['department'] === $testNeedle;
                       }
         ) as $phoneEntry) {
    var_dump($phoneEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For these type of questions, 'array_walk' can be used as well. You should call the below written function as -

```
array_walk($phoneList, 'print_department');
```

The function is:

```
function print_department($phonelist){

    // Printing the items
    if($phonelist['department'] == 'Falmouth'){
        echo $phonelist['name']. '<br>';
        echo $phonelist['telephonenumber']. '<br>';
        echo $phonelist['department']. '<br>';
    }
}
```